# PHP: Defined variable cross methods

Tags: php

I have the followings PHP code:

```
use Dictionary\Parser as Parser;

function recupererCases_mysql_CSPro($conn) {
    /* $sql=('SELECT questionnaire FROM code_machine_dict');
    foreach  ($connexion->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['questionnaire'] . "\n";}
            */
    $casescspro = $conn->query('SELECT questionnaire FROM code_machine_dict WHERE deleted=0 ORDER BY caseids');
    foreach ($casescspro as $row) {
        $questionnaire=$row['questionnaire']. "<br>\n";
        print $questionnaire;
    }       
}

function DictionaryAsTextString($conn) {
    $dcfstring = $conn->query('SELECT dictionary_full_content FROM cspro_dictionaries WHERE dictionary_label="code_machine"');
    foreach ($dcfstring as $row) {
        $dictText=$row['dictionary_full_content'];
        print $dictText;
    }
    return $dictText;
}

function DcfnameTextString($conn) {
    $dcfnamestring = $conn->query('SELECT dictionary_name FROM cspro_dictionaries WHERE dictionary_name = "CODE_MACHINE_DICT"');
    foreach ($dcfnamestring as $row) {
        $dictName=$row['dictionary_name'];
        print $dictName;
    }
    return $dictName;
}

function loadDictionary($conn) {
    $parser = new Parser ();
    try {
        $dict = $parser->parseDictionary ( $dictText );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $csproResponse->setError ( 400, 'dictionary_invalid', $e->getMessage () );
        $csproResponse->setStatusCode ( 400 );
    }
    return $dict;
}
```

but I get compile errors that `dict`, etc. are not defined.

However, they are already defined in previous methods. For example, `$dictText` in function `DictionaryAsTextString($conn)`, `$dictName` in function `DcfnameTextString($conn)` and `$Dict` in `loadDictionary($conn)`.

Additionally, I reference `Parser` in `loadDictionary` which is imported with `use Dictionary\Parser as Parser` but it display error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Dictionary\Parser' not found in  C:\wamp64\www\ui\suivi\Index.php
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: You need to understand scoping.  A variable is only valid within a particular scope.  Outside of that scope it doesn't exist. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: It would help if you provide the compilation errors themselves - it's not clear from your question if this is a problem of scoping, as GordonM says, or is it some other issue where your variables are not recognized in the scope they are defined in.